# how to detect the rising edge of the signal (the rising edge consists of several points)?

Tags: algorithm, signals, signal-processing, edge-detection

I have a signal in

[image: figure 1]

and I want to detect the rising edge of the signal and obtain a curve which has the peak point in the position of (x=147), I have tried to make difference of the signal, but the peak point is in the position of x=144 just like

[image: figure 2].

Therefore, is there any ways to detect the rising edge of the signal in figure 1 and produce a curve which has the peak point in the position of (x=147)?

I want a curve with the peak point in x=147 (just like figure 2) instead of just the number of the location 147.

Comment: The peak in the difference function corresponds to the maximum slope in the curve. A peak in the curve would be where the difference curve is zero. (So perhaps a useful criterion for finding the peak you want might be to find the first zero value after the highest peak in the difference curve.)

Comment: Thanks Oehm, my difference curve here is obtained by doing  f(x=N)-f(x=N-1), so I am a little confused why the peak in the signal would be where the difference curve is zero?  Moreover, do you have any suggestion about how to obtain a curve with the peak point in x=147 (just like figure 2)  instead of finding the point x=147, e.g. some transform like wavelet transform? or any operators else?

Comment: Well, the difference curve is an approximation of the derivative and that's zero where the curve is at a maximum, because the slope changes from positive to negative, no? A transformation or filter might be useful to reduce the noise in the signal, but it might also smoothe out the small peak at x = 147 and just detect the absolute maximum at x = 158, which is hidden by the label in figure 1. It all depends on the use case: sampling rate, measured noise and so on.

Comment: Thanks Oehm, I understand what you meant, I will try other ways to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: X=147 is the last point such that the signal increases. So where's the difficulty ?

Comment: Your last sentence is particularly enigmatic.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I wanted to find a method to directly output a curve in which the peak point is in x=147, it seems like impossiable. Now I have solved the problem by a correction strategy to output the curve i wanted.